# Cryptic Family Reunion: Begins at a boil!

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-clues

The answer to this puzzle is a list of seven thematically related words or proper names or phrases. Each of these is clued cryptically, and the theme is to be determined. Since the definition part of a cryptic clue would give away the theme, these cryptic clues use a family member (e.g., mom, sister) to stand in for the definition part of the clue. So for example, if the theme of the puzzle were chemical elements, "Sister picking at nit" would clue "tin". I hope you enjoy!

1. Niece's complaint about first taxi cab uptown (8)
2. Grandpa recalls crude oil delivery (5,6)
3. Important to include a writer of Python scripts after leaders of Matlab project spurned requirements from sister (4'1 6)
4. Nephew mowed peat, grass in short supply (11)
5. Auntie aggrieved...no alternative (5)
6. Dad sick after May fruit absorbed potassium and antimony (9)
7. Son first to eat up waffle after killing half hour (10)

Bonus: Why only seven clues? "@JeremyDover is getting lazy" would be a correct, but unaccepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are all

> Sea Turtles

Why only seven

> Because there are only seven living species of sea turtle

Answers

> 1. FLATBACK = FLAK about T(axi) + CAB<
>  2. OLIVE RIDLEY = (OIL DELIVERY)*
>  3. KEMP'S RIDLEY = KEY to include M(atlab) P(roject) S(purned) R(equirements) + (eric) IDLE
>  4. LEATHERBACK = LACK around EAT HERB
>  5. GREEN = (a)G(g)R(i)E(v)E(d) N(o)  (solved by Stiv)
>  6. HAWKSBILL = HAW + K + SB + ILL
>  7. LOGGERHEAD = LEAD contains (H(ou)R + EGGO)<

Thanks to Stiv for explanation of #5

Comment: Gah, ninja'd - well done. I was trying to solve those last two (I'm struggling with those as well). You're right about the reason there's only 7 (+1)

Comment: For 5 rot13(gnxr nygreangr yrggref - nTtEvRiRq Ab)

Comment: @Stiv Ah yes thanks, was looking at that for ages. Sorry for ninja, had all the answers so thought it was okay, didn't know if anybody else was looking.

Comment: Wow, that didn't last long :-) #7 relies on a US-centric definition for waffle...sorry about that! Nice work hexomino and @Stiv!!!

Comment: @JeremyDover Thanks I think I get it now.